# Return first non-blank date per account per group - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset:

[image]

How can I get the first non-blank date per account?
[image]

Comment: Is this something you need to do in a measure or in power query while loading the data? How is an account identified, in your example you only have one account ID so I would think you want '1/1/2019' for all rows?

Comment: 1. date is a calculated field, so I guess the option of correcting while loading won't work. 2. No, I need the first date per a block between non-blank rows.

Comment: If date is a calculated field what it the logic used to calculate it while loading it in to Power BI?

Comment: I check if the value on day 2 = value on day 1. If yes, I get the date, if no, leave it as blank.

Comment: It might be better to repost this sharing your PowerQuery code and tagging it as such. I don't think this is something that's best solved within the Power BI front end.

Comment: have you tried the DAX FirstNonBlank function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/firstnonblank-function-dax